# Angular 2 - getting reference to typescript obj in html

Tags: angular, typescript

I am wondering if there is anyway to give an object an isolate scope (I believe that is the right terminology) in my html in inside of a component in my Angular 2 app.  For example, lets say I have this obj in my component TS file:

```
private myObj = { 
  nestedObj1: {
    nestedObj2: {
      nestedObj3: {
        name: 'George',
        height: '72 inches',
        birthday: 'February 31',
        position: 'Engineer',
        favNums: [1, 2, 3, 10, 20]
      }
    }
  }
};
```

In my component HTML is there anyway for me to say something along the lines of:

```
<div *let person = myObj.nestedObj1.nestedObj2.nestedObj3">  // THIS PART!!
    <h2>{{person.name}}</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>{{person.height}}</li>
        <li>{{person.birthday}}</li>
        <li>{{person.position}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Similar how to with an ngFor loop you can do:

```
<div *ngFor="let num of myObj.nestedObj1.nestedObj2.nestedObj3.favNums">
    <p>{{ num }}</p>
</div>
```

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Angular 2 **component**, which always has an isolated scope.

Just put the html as the component's template and store **myObj** as part of the component's scope.

[Here is the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)

[And here is a tutorial for creating one](https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-your-first-angular-2-components)

Comment: thanks for the response.  However, I am familiar with Angular 2 components, I am talking about getting reference to an object on a smaller isolate scope inside a components template, I will edit my question to make that more clear

Comment: You can use one parent and one child component. Keep the myObj data in the parent component and the html structure in the child component. Pass data from the parent to child with binding. The child component will have an isolated scope. Similar to what you wrote in the div as attribute `let person = ...`, but instead `write [person] = "expression"`